# Trying to delete some windows driver file from Manjaro Linux - but it's reappears when I refresh the folder

Tags: linux, windows

I have windows stuck in endless loading loop with ntfs.sys error after recent update. LiveCD or windows installation USB does the same. Fortunately I have Linux on the same SDD and it works. So I'm trying to delete the updated malfunction ntfs.sys from drivers folder and updates folder. But Linux regenerates it when I refresh the folder. Even after remounting the Windows disc with RW permissons (sudo mount -o remount,rw "/run/media/triadasoul/Windows 10" "/run/media/triadasoul/Windows 10).

What should I do - to delete remove that file from windows/system32/drivers folder?

Comment: Without `ntfs.sys` Windows won't boot, and Linux doesn't regenerate Windows files at all. Your analysis of the problem is flawed.

Comment: I'm using linux about 30 minutes - if my analysis would be better I think I wouldn't have that problem. Still my plan that windows won't load and I could recover it from windows live USB. Because that new ntfs.sys is causing those endless loops. There's no answer on Microsoft forums for such a problem I need to invent something.

Comment: Endless boot loops are treated extensively on our site and elsewhere. Just look for it and don't invent : Google [Windows boot loop site:superuser.com](https://www.google.fr/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hl=en-FR&gbv=1&q=Windows+boot+loop+site%3Asuperuser.com&oq=&aqs=) gives about 6,510 results. Take your pick.

Comment: already read first 2 pages of links from google - those who have same problem don't have answers in thread. If I had no linux - I'm unable to start it even with USB.

Comment: I just need the answer how I can delete those files (I'll move them to separate location) that's it.

Comment: I suggest closing this post and asking the real question of why you can't boot.

Comment: No answer there, even downvoted:

https://superuser.com/questions/1775237/windows-11-endless-starting-loop-with-ntfs-sys-error-usb-live-stuck-the-same-wa

Comment: It was probably downvoted as (sorry) a low-quality question. It would need much more information for anyone to suggest anything.

Comment: I see the same problem in both posts.  "ntfs.sys error" tells me nothing.  I don't think deleting the file is going to help you in any way.