# Windows 11 endless starting loop with ntfs.sys error. USB live stuck the same way

Tags: windows

Windows 11 endless starting loop with ntfs.sys error after recent update. USB live stuck the same way. So I don't have opportunity to get to recovery mode or to re-installation routine from USB.

The hardware is ok because I have Linux on the same SSD and it works perfecty.

What can I do to repair or re-install windows?

Comment: Which USB live ?

Comment: Any available out there rescue usb with windows 11 or just microsoft installation usb - tried both

Comment: Do you see in the message which `ntfs.sys` is referred : The one on disk or on the boot media? A screenshot of the boot error could help. Check also in Linux the SMART attributes of the disk ([link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-an-hard-drive-health-from-the-command-line-using-smartctl)).

Comment: I can't get that blue screen it appears after an hour of loading for 2-3 sec. But I've tested with smartscan the windows drive - no errors

Comment: Use the Linux boot in order to position to `C:\Windows\Minidump` and post one or more recent `.dmp` files online for us (OneDrive, Dropbox etc). Zip them up for compactness. Let me me know - add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.

Comment: Here's the latest dump: 
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bla7qy7mncdgiqb/031523-8890-01.dmp?dl=0) 
@harrymc

Answer (score 0):

The analysis of the `.dmp` crash file shows the error as
[Bug Check 0x1AA: EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_STACK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x1aa-exception-on-invalid-stack):

> This BugCheck indicates that exception dispatch crossed over into an invalid kernel stack. This might indicate that the kernel stack pointer has become corrupted during exception dispatch or unwind (e.g. due to stack corruption of a frame pointer), or that a driver is executing off of a stack that is not a legal kernel stack.

The text is not particularly helpful, but bug check 1A is usually
invoked by the memory manager, when detecting bad values or bad behavior.
You need to find whether it is caused by hardware or software.

These steps could help :

- Check the Hardware Compatibility of your PC for Windows 11,
  and return to Windows 10 if it was previously installed and working
  on this computer
- Reset RAM
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours,
  over-night will be good
- Verify the SMART attributes of the disk under Linux with
  [SMART tests with smartctl](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl).
  Add the test results to your post if you wish for our opinion.
- Run any available BIOS hardware test
- Reinstall Windows.

Comment: Internet is full of such "solutions". The only conclusion is to buy a new SSD instead of this locked with windows/linux right?

Check whatever (the overnight memory test is most usefull of all) - everything works well under linux, even heavy games under proton. I just can't access any windows recovery/reinstallation routine even from USB flash drive - that's the problem.

Windows 11 worked on the same hardware since release until last week update.

Also I can't access windows partition for writing from linux because it wasn't properly shutdown and it was locked by windows.

Comment: Windows can't "lock" a partition. If the partition is now unreachable from Linux, then the disk has indeed encountered a catastrophic error. It would be very simple to say "buy a new disk" for any disk crash, the idea is instead to be sure that the disk is not salvageable. And I'm not 100% convinced that your problem is with the disk. But if you prefer not running the tests, it's your choice.

Comment: it's reachable (I can copy any of it's contents anywhere in Linux) but even with remounting - it tells that I should shut-down windows properly to have the access to change.

using ntfs-3g
"The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only"

I already run smartscan - it tells everything is ok. SDD is ok.

Comment: Please read carefully - my problem is that I can't get to any menu from where I can reinstall windows/format sdd even when I'm running windows installation/resque USB because it somehow reuses that bugged windows installed with the same result.